# Plot variables out of differential equations system function

Tags: python-2.7, plot, differential-equations

I have a 4-4 differential equations system in a function (subsystem4) and I solved it with odeint funtion. I managed to plot the results of the system. My problem is that I want to plot and some other equations (e.g. x,y,vcxdot...) which are included in the same function (subsystem4) but I get NameError: name 'vcxdot' is not defined. Also, I want to use some of these equations (not only the results of the equation's system) as inputs in a following differential equations system and plot all the equations in the same period of time (t). I have done this using Matlab-Simulink but it was much easier because of Simulink blocks. How can I have access to and plot all the equations of a function (subsystem4) and use them as input in a following system? I am new in python and I use Python 2.7.12. Thank you in advance!

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def subsystem4(u,t):
    added_mass_x = 0.03 # kg
    added_mass_y = 0.04
    mb = 0.3 # kg
    m1 = mb-added_mass_x
    m2 = mb-added_mass_y
    l1 = 0.07 # m
    l2 = 0.05 # m
    J = 0.00050797 # kgm^2
    Sa = 0.0110 # m^2
    Cd = 2.44
    Cl = 3.41
    Kd = 0.000655 # kgm^2
    r = 1000 # kg/m^3
    f = 2 # Hz
    c1 = 0.5*r*Sa*Cd
    c2 = 0.5*r*Sa*Cl
    c3 = 0.5*mb*(l1**2)
    c4 = Kd/J
    c5 = (1/(2*J))*(l1**2)*mb*l2
    c6 = (1/(3*J))*(l1**3)*mb


    vcx = u[0]
    vcy = u[1]
    psi = u[2]
    wz = u[3]

    x = 3 + 0.3*np.cos(t)
    y = 0.5 + 0.3*np.sin(t)
    xdot = -0.3*np.sin(t)
    ydot = 0.3*np.cos(t)
    xdotdot = -0.3*np.cos(t)
    ydotdot = -0.3*np.sin(t)
    vcx = xdot*np.cos(psi)-ydot*np.sin(psi)
    vcy = ydot*np.cos(psi)+xdot*np.sin(psi)

    psidot = wz
    vcxdot = xdotdot*np.cos(psi)-xdot*np.sin(psi)*psidot-ydotdot*np.sin(psi)-ydot*np.cos(psi)*psidot
    vcydot = ydotdot*np.cos(psi)-ydot*np.sin(psi)*psidot+xdotdot*np.sin(psi)+xdot*np.cos(psi)*psidot
    g1 = -(m1/c3)*vcxdot+(m2/c3)*vcy*wz-(c1/c3)*vcx*np.sqrt((vcx**2)+(vcy**2))+(c2/c3)*vcy*np.sqrt((vcx**2)+(vcy**2))*np.arctan2(vcy,vcx)
    g2 = (m2/c3)*vcydot+(m1/c3)*vcx*wz+(c1/c3)*vcy*np.sqrt((vcx**2)+(vcy**2))+(c2/c3)*vcx*np.sqrt((vcx**2)+(vcy**2))*np.arctan2(vcy,vcx)

    A = 12*np.sin(2*np.pi*f*t+np.pi)
    if A>=0.1:
        wzdot = ((m1-m2)/J)*vcx*vcy-c4*wz**2*np.sign(wz)-c5*g2-c6*np.sqrt((g1**2)+(g2**2))
    elif A<-0.1:
        wzdot = ((m1-m2)/J)*vcx*vcy-c4*wz**2*np.sign(wz)-c5*g2+c6*np.sqrt((g1**2)+(g2**2))
    else:
        wzdot = ((m1-m2)/J)*vcx*vcy-c4*wz**2*np.sign(wz)-c5*g2


    return [vcxdot,vcydot,psidot,wzdot]

u0 = [0,0,0,0]
t = np.linspace(0,15,1000)
u = odeint(subsystem4,u0,t)

vcx = u[:,0]
vcy = u[:,1]
psi = u[:,2]
wz = u[:,3]

plt.figure(1)
plt.subplot(211)
plt.plot(t,vcx,'r-',linewidth=2,label='vcx')
plt.plot(t,vcy,'b--',linewidth=2,label='vcy')
plt.plot(t,psi,'g:',linewidth=2,label='psi')
plt.plot(t,wz,'c',linewidth=2,label='wz')
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Why do you have `vcx, vcy` as state components when they are completely known by `t,psi` and their derivatives with the additional `psidot = wz`? Are the paths of `x,y` really given as parameters or is this a partial solution for this component of the system?

Comment: @LutzL Do you mean that it could be a simpler 2-2 system instead of 4-4? You might be right. However, I still cannot put the equations of xdot, ydot,, xdotdot, y dotdot, vcx, vcy and their derivatives out of the function because they are necessary for the solution and I cannot access them from outside of the function to plot them with time.

Comment: Can you put up your complete model or a simplified mock-up that still has the same difficulty?

Comment: code updated (full version of the code so far. Model is still the same). I want to be able to plot all the variables from the function that change with time and use some of them as input in a following subsystem (this code is not ready yet).

Comment: can you explain what do you mean by applying 'udot = subsystem4(u,t)' to the solution of the odeint? If I use the line as it is I get 'ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1000,) (4,)'

Comment: The system seems to have some redundancies built in. Also the computation of `g1,g2` seems suspect in the last term, as the angle computed there, "`pi/2+t+psi` reduced to `(-pi,pi]`" has arbitrary (?) jumps and seems misplaced as "naked" angle, with no trig. function around it.

Answer (score 0):

To the immediate question of plotting the derivatives, you can get the velocities by directly calling the ODE function again on the solution,

```
u = odeint(subsystem4,u0,t)
udot = subsystem4(u.T,t)
```

and get the separate velocity arrays via

```
vcxdot,vcydot,psidot,wzdot = udot
```

---

In this case the function involves branching, which is not very friendly to vectorized calls of it. There are ways to vectorize branching, but the easiest work-around is to loop manually through the solution points, which is slower than a working vectorized implementation. This will again procude a list of tuples like `odeint`, so the result has to be transposed as a tuple of lists for "easy" assignment to the single array variables.

```
udot = [ subsystem4(uk, tk) for uk, tk in zip(u,t) ]; 
vcxdot,vcydot,psidot,wzdot = np.asarray(udot).T
```

[image: extended plot]

---

This may appear to double somewhat the computation, but not really, as the solution points are usually interpolated from the internal step points of the solver. The evaluation of the ODE function during integration will usually happen at points that are different from the solution points.

For the other variables, extract the computation of position and velocities into functions to have the constant and composition in one place only:

```
def xy_pos(t): return 3 + 0.3*np.cos(t), 0.5 + 0.3*np.sin(t)
def xy_vel(t): return -0.3*np.sin(t), 0.3*np.cos(t) 
def xy_acc(t): return -0.3*np.cos(t), -0.3*np.sin(t)
```

or similar that you can then use both inside the ODE function and in preparing the plots.

---

What Simulink most likely does is to collect all the equations of all the blocks and form this into one big ODE system which is then solved for the whole state at once. You will need to implement something similar. One big state vector, and each subsystem knows its slice of the state resp. derivatives vector to get its specific state variables from and write the derivatives to. The computation of the derivatives can then use values communicated among the subsystems.

What you are trying to do, solving the subsystems separately, works only for resp. will likely result in a order 1 integration method. All higher order methods need to be able to simultaneously shift the state in some direction computed from previous stages of the method, and evaluate the whole system there.

Comment: if I get it correctly, I have to make a big function including all the equations from all the subsystems and one big state vector. Then I will use the odeint function out of the main function to solve the whole system at once using a big initial conditions vector. If it's ok so far, how can I access variables from the function that are not state variables (xdotdot), or the derivatives of the state variables (vcxdot) in order to plot them?

Comment: changing my code to: 
'u = odeint(subsystem4,u0,t)'
'udot = subsystem4(u,t)'
'vcxdot,vcydot,psidot,wzdot = udot.T'
I get the following error: 
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1000,) (4,)

Comment: Yes, that might be the order of indices. Try the transpose, `udot = subsystem4(u.T,t)`. Then after that the result already should have the correct index order, thus `vcxdot,vcydot,psidot,wzdot = udot`.

Comment: adding the lines:
'udot = subsystem4(u.T,t)
vcxdot,vcydot,psidot,wzdot = udot' gave me the error:
if A>=0.1:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all(). That is really weird since I didn't change anything in the logical operation

Comment: Yes, branching is not very compatible with vectorization. There are ways, but the easiest work-around it then to loop manually through the solution points, which is slower than a working vectorized implementation. `udot = [ subsystem4(uk, tk) for uk, tk in zip(u,t) ]; vcxdot,vcydot,psidot,wzdot = np.asarray(udot).T`.